# Trouble in installing j2se 1.4 or higher

Tags: java, java1.4

I have a intel core i3 (not the 2nd generation i3) processor and windows 7 64 bit OS.
Which j2se 1.4 should i install from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html#j2sdk-1.4.2_30-sol-JPR this website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be installing JDK 1.4 at all - it's well past its supported life.

I took a peek at the link you provided.  It looks to me like Oracle will only make older versions of the JDK available for Solaris.  I doubt that there was ever a version that ran on that version of Windows.  Why port it now?

You're out of luck.

I'd recommend an upgrade to JDK 6 or higher.  JDK 7 is the latest standard.  You should be keeping up with your JDK, just as you are with your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

There's Windows versions available of update 19 here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html#j2sdk-1.4.2_19-oth-JPR

They were never designed to work on Windows 7 though, let alone 64 bit - so I can't guarantee they'll work (and if they don't then Oracle won't do anything to try to make them work because of the age!)

I'd also seriously question your motive for requiring 1.4, and recommend you migrate to a current, supported version of the JDK. If nothing else remember there's no security updates, so any exploits that are found won't be patched.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a 32-bit version of Java from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html

I use such a 32-bit Java on a regular basis under Windows 7 64-bit directly from the command line.

That said, newer versions of Java perform better and you should only use Java 1.4 if you need to support it or have software that explicitly requre Java 1.4.

The latest version of Java 7 supports 64-bit and is tested under Windows 7.